# How to reduce the thickness of a horizontal scroll bar of a tile list in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am having a Horizontal tile list, i want to customize the style of the horizontal scroll bar of this tile list. I want to reduce the thickness of the scroll bar so that it looks as a thick line or something. Even i dont want the arrows at the either side of the scroll bar. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

In flex 3 it is possible to skin the scrollbar in CSS:

```
mx|ScrollBar 
{
    up-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null); //removes up arrow
    down-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null); // removes down arrow
    trackSkin: Embed(source="assets/ScrollBarTrack.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
    thumbUpSkin: Embed(source="assets/ScrollBarThumb_up.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
    thumbOverSkin: Embed(source="assets/ScrollBarThumb_over.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
    thumbDownSkin: Embed(source="assets/ScrollBarThumb_down.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
}
```

In flex 4 you would want to write a custom skin.

Comment: Thanks Baris. but what if i dont want to use any images for Skinning. I want to make it using may be CSS or any internal thickness property

Comment: You might need to create a skin for that. Check : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_5.html